# ActionPerformed and passing an object

Tags: java

`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == saleButton)
        {
            processSale(Wine wi);
            //System.out.println("fvghj");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == returnButton)
        {
                processReturn(Wine wi);
            //System.out.println("fdgchj"); 
        }

    }


    //create a wine object to be returned - responsible for getting details from textfields when either sale or return is pressed
    //this object is then passed to the relevant method in LWMGUI to process either sale or return


public Wine getWine()
    {
        String wName = nameWineText.getText();

        String costBottles = costBottleText.getText();
        int cBottle = Integer.parseInt(costBottles);
        //System.out.println(cBottle);

        //get numBottle
        String numBottles = numBottlesText.getText();
        int nBottle = Integer.parseInt(numBottles);
        //System.out.println(nBottle);

        Wine wi = new Wine(wName, cBottle, nBottle);

        return wi;

    }


    private int processSale(Wine wi)
    {
        int totalSaleAmount = wi.getNumBottle() * (int) wi.getCostBottle();
        //System.out.println(totalAmount);
        transactionText.setText("" + totalSaleAmount);
        return totalSaleAmount;
    }

    private int processReturn(Wine wi)
    {
        int totalReturnAmount = wi.getNumBottle() * (int) wi.getCostBottle();
        //System.out.println(totalReturnAmount);
        transactionText.setText("" + totalReturnAmount);
        return totalReturnAmount;
    }
```

`I'm having problems with an actionPerformed method.  I have got text from user input textfields to give me the cost, quantity and name of a wine, for a sale or return to be processed.  I have created a Wine object (wi) with this information, and want to pass it to further methods, whether sale or return.

I can't get the processSale() or processReturn() methods to work, and I'm really confused!!  I thought passing the Wine wi object to the methods would work?
Here is the relevant code;

Comment: processSale(Wine wi); Here you are creating a variable. But you should pass an object like processSale(new Wine())

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
processSale(getWine())
```

Or

```
processReturn(getWine())
```

Actually all the time you are sending a new instance of wine having nothing. So your those two methods are always having a null instance of wine